# I am trying to write to a text file a username/password login system and am uncertain how to fix a few errors

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Login_System
{
public partial class users : Form
{
    public users()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    String[] username = Program.User.Username;
    String[] password = Program.User.Password;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userNum = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        username[userNum] = textBox1.Text;
        password[userNum] = textBox2.Text;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userNum = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        username[userNum] = "laksdjfh";
        password[userNum] = "laksdjfh";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String[] print = { username[0] + " " + password[0], username[1] + " " +         password[1], username[2] + " " + password[2], username[3] + " " + password[3], username[4] + " " + password[4], username[5] + " " + password[5], username[6] + " " + password[6], username[7] + " " + password[7], username[8] + " " + password[8], username[9] + " " + password[9], username[10] + " " + password[10], username[11] + " " + password[11], username[12] + " " + password[12], username[13] + " " + password[13], username[14] + " " + password[14], username[15] + " " + password[15], username[16] + " " + password[16], username[17] + " " + password[17], username[18] + " " + password[18], username[19] + " " + password[19] };
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"Users.txt", print);
    }
}
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.

namespace Login_System
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string request;
            User nonAdmin = new User();
            User Admin = new User();
            Admin.username[0] = "sysadmin";
            Admin.password[0] = "abc123";
            Console.Write("Username:");
            string entry = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("password:");
            string pass = Console.ReadLine();
            if (entry == Admin.username[0] && pass == Admin.password[0])
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                    request = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (request == "modify user")
                    {
                        Application.Run(new users());
                    }
                    else if (request == "run")
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to run? (dont forget the file extention!)");
                        string program = Console.ReadLine();
                        runprogram(program);
                }
                    else if (request == "log out")
                    {
                           break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error, not an option");
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
            {
                if (entry == nonAdmin.username[i] && pass == nonAdmin.password[i])
                {
                while (true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
                        request = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (request == "run")
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("What would you like to run? (dont forget the file extention!)");
                            string program = Console.ReadLine();
                        runprogram(program);
                        }
                        else if (request == "log out")
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                    {
                            Console.WriteLine("Error, not an option");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        static void runprogram (string program)
        {
            try
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = program;
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-n";
                process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch{}
        }
        public class User
        {
            public  String[] username = { "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh" };
            public  String[] password = { "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh", "laksdjfh" };
            public  String[] Username
            {
            get { return username; }
                set { username = value; }
            }
            public  String[] Password
            {
                get { return password; }
                set { password = value; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the errors that "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Login_System.Program.User.Username.get'" at line 19 column 29 and at line 18 column 29 in the first code block I showed you and that "Member 'Login_System.Program.User.username' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead" at line 20 column 18 in the second block of code. I am trying to do this and I am honestly clueless on what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** you are trying to access the non-static feilds with class name directly.

**Solution :** you need an instance variable to access the non-static feilds.

Replace This:

```
String[] username = Program.User.Username;
String[] password = Program.User.Password;
```

With This:

```
Program.User user1=new Program.User();
String[] username = user1.Username;
String[] password = user1.Password;
```

**Solution 2:**
Try to put your above statements in constructor of users class.

```
Program.User user1;
String[] username;
String[] password;
public users()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    user1 =new Program.User();
    username = user1.Username;
    passord = user1.Password;
}
```

Comment: That results in the error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'Login_System.users.user1'"

Comment: @Dominik:please check my edited answer with `solution2`

Comment: Ok that is fixed but I still have the error "Member 'Login_System.Program.User.username' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead E:\Login System\Login System\Program.cs" in line 20 column 18 of the second code block

Comment: @Dominik: i can not identify which line is 20 from your posted code, so colud you please tell me your line 20?

Comment: it is the Admin.username[0] = "sysadmin"; line

Comment: try `Admin.username = new String[]{"sysadmin"};`